# wp-cli: run post generate and post meta add together

Tags: wp-cli

I would like to generate a number of posts and attach the same featured image to all posts.

```
wp post generate --count=20
wp post meta add <id> _thumbnail_id 215
```

But how can I run this two commands together? How can I retrieve the id of created post?

Answer (score 2):

As I [mentioned on the Github issue](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/2224), your request isn't currently possible with WP-CLI but would be a nice future enhancement.